# Windows 10 Pro can not enter Standby (S3)

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep

I just recently reinstalled Windows 10 Pro and initially everything worked properly. However, the S3 Standby is not available anymore. Running `powercfg /a` gives:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>powercfg /a
The following sleep states are available on this system:
Hibernate

The following sleep states are not available on this system:
Standby (S1)
The system firmware does not support this standby state.

Standby (S2)
The system firmware does not support this standby state.

Standby (S3)
The system firmware does not support this standby state.

Standby (S0 Low Power Idle)
The system firmware does not support this standby state.

Hybrid Sleep
Standby (S3) is not available.
The hypervisor does not support this standby state.

Fast Startup
This action is disabled in the current system policy.
```

I already reset my BIOS settings and changed my group policies as in this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/1179987/activate-sleep-states-after-win10-install).
I also updated my graphics drivers and installed the latest AMD chipset driver.
I have a MSI x370 Gaming Pro Carbon motherboard and a Ryzen 1700.

## Edit

I managed to fix it enabling SMT. Seemingly S3 Standby is not available if SMT is deactivated.

Comment: Did you re-install / update the Power Management Driver?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no specific power management driver for my motherboard/chipset.

Comment: Look in the power plan settings and see what the buttons do. Power plan settings in newer Windows versions have moved from Advanced settings to settings within the Power Plan window. Try that.

Comment: Already checked that. There is not Standby option there only fast-boot, hibernation and lock.

Comment: What's SMT? and where did you enable it?