# Regedit solution to activate sleep states on Windows 10 (gpedit.msc unavailable)

Tags: windows-10, sleep, regedit, hybrid-sleep

ETA: to clarify, my sleep settings S1, S2, S3, and hybrid sleep are disabled when viewed through the command prompt using `powercfg /a`:

```
The following sleep states are available on this system:
    Standby (S0 Low Power Idle) Network Connected
    Hibernate
    Fast Startup

The following sleep states are not available on this system:
    Standby (S1)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.
        This standby state is disabled when S0 low power idle is supported.

    Standby (S2)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.
        This standby state is disabled when S0 low power idle is supported.

    Standby (S3)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.
        This standby state is disabled when S0 low power idle is supported.

    Hybrid Sleep
        Standby (S3) is not available.
```

I found this thread and it seems like just what I need:

[How to activate sleep states after Windows 10 install](https://superuser.com/questions/1179987/how-to-activate-sleep-states-after-windows-10-install)

I  have exactly the same problem, except hibernate is fine for me. I'm just missing S1, S2, and S3 (including hybrid sleep), which means my computer can't sleep. So this solution sounds like it should work for me:

> gpedit.msc -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Power Management -> Sleep Settings

And it looks like the OP there had the same problem as me: I have the home edition, and I tried a bunch of ways to enable gpedit.msc and none have worked. I read somewhere that everything you can do in in gpedit.msc can be accomplished in the registry editor: is that true? Does anyone know the regedit solution to re-enabling sleep?

I'm fairly certain that I had the option for hybrid sleep when I first got this computer. I remember having an issue with it going to sleep too often that I think I fixed with regedit, but of course that might have been what broke S1-S3 in the first place. I just can't find the threads... I really should have written down what I was changing.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1018145/windows-starter-edition-home-and-home-premium-do-not-include-gpedit-how-do-i-i) still works.  But you have not specified which policy you want to edit by using the associated registry key. [This](https://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/Default_legacy.aspx?PolicyID=7917) website lists each registry key for each policy (since you haven’t specified which policies you are looking to configure)

Comment: [PolicyPlus](https://github.com/Fleex255/PolicyPlus) can also be used

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; Policy Plus did have the settings I needed, but when I enabled them, quit, and restarted, the settings I had enabled were set to Not Configured again. I downloaded the gpedit.msc solution you suggested, but the Power Management folder does not exist inside Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\ for me.

Comment: What about the keys themselves. does not matter what PolicyPlus thought the value was, that was just a tool to find the correct registry key.

Comment: I went to  Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Power\PowerSettings\94ac6d29-73ce-41a6-809f-6363ba21b47e and added the DWORDs ACSettingIndex and DCSettingIndex, and set their values both to 1. (I had to create the Power, PowerSettings, and 94ac6d29-73ce-41a6-809f-6363ba21b47e keys.) It didn't do anything. I can't figure out which other keys need settings changed to enable S1, S2, and S3 sleep modes.

Comment: Unlike the Local Group Policy Editor, Policy Plus does not save automatically. You need to use *File | Save Policies* (Ctrl+S) after making your changes. However, I suspect making policy/Registry changes can only help with "the current power policy has disabled this standby state"; it probably will not make a difference if Windows does not find firmware support for the power state.